# Spring @RequestMapping Nested Behavior

Tags: spring-mvc

How is `@RequestMapping` supposed to behave in the following situation?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/search")
public class SearchController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String search(ModelMap map) {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

I have a project that has had this config for several years and responded to requests like `www.domain.com/appname/search`. After a very small update in which the controller was untouched the app now only responds to `www.domain.com/appname/search/search`.

I would have expected the latter behavior originally but what would cause it to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller should handle requests for `www.domain.com/appname/search/search`.

The cause of the change turned out to be updating the `spring-webmvc` dependency from version 3.1.1 to 3.2.2. I checked out the change logs and didn't see anything that would indicate this particular change, but testing determined it to be the case.

The `spring-webmvc` dependency brings in transitive dependencies for `spring-context`, `spring-core`, `spring-aop`, `spring-web`, `spring-beans`, `spring-expression` and others depending on what version you are using. In any case, these all moved from 3.1.1 to 3.2.2 and somewhere along the lines changed this behavior.